# Moving between "pages" ( CCLayer ) in cocos2dx

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I have 2 MyGameScreen objects that extends cocos2d::CCLayer. I am capturing the ccTouchesMove of the first screen so that I can create the moving effect exactly like sliding between pages of iOS application screen.

My class is like so:

```
class MyGameScreen: public cocos2d::CCLayer {
    cocos2d::CCLayer* m_pNextScreen;
}

bool MyGameScreen::init() {
    m_pNextScreen = MyOtherScreen::create();
}

void MyGameScreen::ccTouchesMoved(CCSet *touches, CCEvent *event){
    // it crashes here... on the setPosition... m_pNextScreen is valid pointer though I am not sure that MyOtherScreen::create() is all I need to do...
    m_pNextScreen->setPosition( CCPointMake( (fMoveTo - (2*fScreenHalfWidth)), 0.0f ) );
}
```

EDIT: adding clear question

It crashed when I try to setPosition on m_pNextScreen...

I have no idea why it crashed as m_pNextScreen is a valid pointer and is properly initialized. Could anybody explain why?

EDIT: adding progress report

I remodelled the whole system and make a `class CContainerLayer : public cocos2d::CCLayer` that contains both `MyGameScreen` and `MyOtherScreen` side by side. However, this looked like not an efficient approach, as when it grows I may need to have more than 2 pages scrollable side by side, I'd prefer to load the next page only when it is needed rather than the entire `CContainerLayer` that contains all the upcoming pages whether the user will scroll there or not... Do you have any better idea or github open source sample that does this?

Thank you very much for your input!

Comment: what is the code in the create method? Does it create an autorelease object which you aren't retaining?

Comment: it is just typical CCLayer `init()` method, I didn't add anything... it is ok if it is pushed with CCTransitionScene... I am wondering if it is because I do not call `this->addChild(m_pNextScreen)` but the next screen shouldn't be the child of this screen...

Comment: You didn't ask a question. What do you want to know?

Answer (score 1):

Use paging enable scrollview.download files from following link and place in your cocos2d/extenision/gui/ after that you have to set property of scrollview to enablepaging true with paging view size.

https://github.com/shauket/paging-scrollview

Answer (score 0):

**For Scene Transitions you can do this:**

void MyGameScreen::ccTouchesMoved(CCSet *touches, CCEvent *event)

{

CCScene* MyOtherScene = CCTransitionFadeUp::create(0.2f, MyOtherScreen::scene());

CCDirector::sharedDirector()->replaceScene(MyOtherScene);

}